# Flexviews Unknown column 'ERROR: XYZ UNSUPPORTED REFRESH METHOD' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql

Whenever I try to execute this query:

```
call flexviews.refresh(flexviews.get_id('data_db','site_folder'),'BOTH',NULL);
```

I get this error:

```
Unknown column 'ERROR:  XYZ UNSUPPORTED REFRESH METHOD' in 'field list'
```

BOTH is a valid refresh method as I checked the source code documentation. I don't know what I'm missing here. The error seems generic 'XYZ'?

I am using this project btw: http://code.google.com/p/flexviews/

Answer (score 0):

I just have to make sure that the table exist as the **second parameter** of `flexviews.get_id()` requires.